# Checking to see if an inputted object is included in an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
    boolean run = true;
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter A to add, S to search, E to exit");
        String temp = input.next();
    switch(temp)
    {
        case "A":
        case "a":
            System.out.println("Please enter the building name: ");
            newClassroom.setBuildingName(input.next());
            System.out.println("Please enter the room number: ");
            newClassroom.setRoomNumber(input.next());
            System.out.println("Please enter the capacity: ");
            newClassroom.setCapacity(input.nextInt());
            System.out.println("Please enter the academic department: ");
            newClassroom.setAcadDept(input.next());
            System.out.println("Please enter whether or not the room has a projector: ");
            newClassroom.setProjector(input.nextBoolean());
            List.add(newClassroom);
            break;
        case "S":
        case "s":
            System.out.println("Enter the building name and room number you wish to locate");
            //String buildingSearch = input.next();
            //int roomSearch = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(List);
            //System.out.println(buildingSearch + roomSearch);
            Classroom temporary = new Classroom();
            temporary.setBuildingName(input.next());
            temporary.setRoomNumber(input.next());

            break;
        case "E":
        case "e":
            System.exit(0);
    }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to check and see if an object is included in the ArrayList.  I've tried using contains, but someone said I should try and use .equals() instead.

Comment: contains() should work fine. Are you having any issues with contains()?

Comment: Someone is wrong, Contains will iterate over the list and check every value with the .equals() method. there is no need for you to provide your own implementation for Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Both are required. You have to override `equals()` method in `ClassRoom` class which compare with other `ClassRoom` object with e.g Room number( depends on you how you are going to implement it). 
Now when `contains()` method will be called, it will check each `ClassRoom` object by invoking `equals()` method and comparing Room no. If it is already there it will return true.

```
class ClassRoom {
     int roomNo;

     public ClassRoom(int r) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         this.roomNo = r;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ClassRoom cr = (ClassRoom)obj;
        return this.roomNo == cr.roomNo;
    }
 }

class TestContains {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        ClassRoom c1 = new ClassRoom(5);
        ClassRoom c2 = new ClassRoom(6);
        ClassRoom c3 = new ClassRoom(7);
        List<ClassRoom> list = new ArrayList<ClassRoom>();
        list.add(c1);
        list.add(c2);
        list.add(c3);

        ClassRoom c8 = new ClassRoom(8);
        ClassRoom c7 = new ClassRoom(7);
        System.out.println(list.contains(c8));
        System.out.println(list.contains(c7));



    }
}
```

> Output :

false

true